# Download created files from iPhone App's document folder on PC

Tags: ios, iphone, file, sharing

I created some files which store some logging information in my iPhone App. They are stored in the App's document folder. I would like to download them onto my Mac. I'm able to see them in the xCode organizer but I'm not able to access these files. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, set `Application supports iTunes file sharing` on on your project's settings plist. It could also be named `UIFileSharingEnabled`.
[image]

Then, for the code, save the file in `NSDocumentDirectory` like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Id its a local file in the app use its name.  If not, alter for your needs.
    NSString *fileName = @"someFile.png";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
 
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath]) {
        NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
       [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
    return YES;
}
```

All taken from [iOS Dev Tips - File Sharing from App to iTunes is too easy](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/11/file-sharing-from-app-to-itunes-is-too.html)

Comment: See sho's answer below, and you don't need to enable file sharing.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Organizer]

Using the Download button in the Organizer allows you to save a `.xcappdata` package to your Mac (Xcode 4.2, previous versions just save a folder). You can right-click and choose "Show Package Contents", a Finder window will open and you can find a copy of the Documents directory therein.